# SAS Data formatting (reverse proc transpose?)

Tags: sas

```
    Q1  Q2  Q3   Q4
A   1   2   3   4
B   1   2   3   4
C   1   2   3   
D   1   2       
E   1   2   3   4
```

I have data like above and would like to import and reshape the data into what it looks like below:

```
    Qtr var1
A   Q1  1
A   Q2  2
A   Q3  3
A   Q4  4
B   Q1  1
B   Q2  2
B   Q3  3
B   Q4  4
C   Q1  1
C   Q2  2
C   Q3  3
D   Q1  1
D   Q2  2
E   Q1  1
E   Q2  2
E   Q3  3
E   Q4  4
```

It seems like a 'proc transpose' but it's reversed.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not stick with PROC TRANSPOSE.  It can do wide to long as well as long to wide.

```
data have;
input ID $ Q1  Q2  Q3   Q4;
datalines;
A   1   2   3   4
B   1   2   3   4
C   1   2   3   .
D   1   2   .   . 
E   1   2   3   4
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want name=Qtr;
by ID;
run;
```

Comment: oh gash. It works. I thought it only did it one way not the other. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept is the data step array.

```
data want;
set have;
array qs q1-q4;
do _t = 1 to dim(qs);
  quarter=vname(qs[_t]);
  var1=qs[_t];
  output;
end;
drop _t;
run;
```

Comment: Joe, thank you for the response. Is there any way that I could do this without specifying the variable names with the array statement?

Comment: That depends wholly on your data.  You could say `array qs Q:;` to have all Q's included; you could say `array qs _numeric_;` to have all numeric variables included.