# How to transform (transpose) a dataset in SAS, so that variables names become class identifiers?

Tags: dataset, sas

How do I transform, with a help of sas code, the following table:

```
ID   T       U
1   1253    1349
2   1139    1382
3   1633    1663
4   1372    1541
5   1502    1335
```

into this table?

```
ClassID     All
T          1253
T          1139
T          1633
T          1372
T          1502
U          1349
U          1382
U          1663
U          1541
U          1335
```

PS: I did try using sas sql to (join all), but could not convert the T and U variables into class identifiers)

Comment: Lots of answers to this question - [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268796/transposing-wide-to-long-with-an-array-in-sas), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981771/sas-data-formatting-reverse-proc-transpose/19984482#19984482), etc.  Search "[sas] wide to long".

Comment: And those of you with 3k+ rep - please search for duplicates before posting answers to things that will certainly have answers :)

Comment: @Joe Yes you're right, my question looks  very very similar to your suggested duplicates questions. I searched in Google for sas table transform, of course it didn't come to my mind to use search like "sas transpose wide to long", until now I was simply unaware of this sas terminology. But I think my duplicate question now has three best answers to the transform/transpose dataset type of questions. And that's why I love duplicates and semi-duplicates :) I will include the word transpose in the question title, to make it more relevant. Fill free to edit it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid hard coding any values, create an array that loops through each record and uses the `vname` function to read the current variable name.  This variable name is assigned to ClassID and the variable value assigned to All.  My code works if all the variables are numeric, you'll need to tweak it if you have a mixture of numeric and character variables (just create another array for the character variables if that's the case).

```
/* create initial dataset */
data have;
input ID T U;
datalines;
1   1253    1349
2   1139    1382
3   1633    1663
4   1372    1541
5   1502    1335
;
run;

/* transform data into required dataset */
data want (keep=classid all); /* only keep wanted variables */
set have (drop=ID); /* don't read in ID as it's not needed */
array vars{*} _numeric_; /* set up array of all remaining variables (assume all numeric) */
do i = 1 to dim(vars); /* loop through each value */
    classID=vname(vars{i}); /* set ClassID to current variable name */
    all = vars{i}; /* set All to current value */
    output;
end;
run;

/* sort data by ClassID */
proc sort data=want;
by classid;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate and very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is what `PROC TRANSPOSE` was created to do.  If you want the records sorted by the new ClassID variable then you will need to also add a `PROC SORT`.

```
proc transpose data=have
  out=want(rename=(_name_=ClassID col1=All))
;
  by id ;
  var T U ;
run;

proc sort;
  by classid id;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you code works well, but I used code from the below answer, so had to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute force method using a DATA step:

```
data test;
  input ID T U;
  cards;
1   1253    1349
2   1139    1382
3   1633    1663
4   1372    1541
5   1502    1335
;

data test;
  set test;
  keep ClassID All;
  ClassID = "T"; All = T; output;
  ClassID = "U"; All = U; output;
proc sort data=test out=test;
  by ClassID;
run;
```